# How to change the read more color button in wpbackery grid (wordpress)?

Tags: css, wordpress, grid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNSym.png)

How can I change the color of this read more button ?
I am using wpbackery plugin to make the posts grid.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out

```
.vc_btn3.vc_btn3-color-juicy-pink, .vc_btn3.vc_btn3-color-juicy-pink.vc_btn3-style-flat {
    background-color: #6b61f4;
}
```

and this for hover

```
> .vc_btn3.vc_btn3-color-juicy-pink:hover,
> .vc_btn3.vc_btn3-color-juicy-pink.vc_btn3-style-flat:hover {  
> background-color: #6b61f4;  }
```